# How do I get groupID in whatsapp-web.js

Tags: javascript, whatsapp

I'm developing a whatsapp bot,
In order to put the bot up (It's 1 group bot), I need to get the groupId,
I've tried to understand how do I get that but I couldn't make it,
Please Help

I tried to get the groupId, it aint easy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What library are you using exactly and programming language?